# Trying to use file encryption but am getting an error with File.Encrypt(FileName) returning an exception

Tags: c#

I tried codeproject help as well as MSDN but no success. Here is a copy of my test code returning an exception:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Decrypt("Text.pvf");
    string[] DataFile = File.ReadAllLines("Text.pvf");
    if (DataFile[5] == "6")
        MessageBox.Show("Encrypt/Decrypt successful");
   //Application.Exit();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] DataFile = new string[6];
    DataFile[0] = "1";
    DataFile[1] = "2";
    DataFile[2] = "3";
    DataFile[3] = "4";
    DataFile[4] = "5";
    DataFile[5] = "6";
    File.WriteAllLines("Text.pvf", DataFile);

    File.Encrypt("Text.pvf");
}
```

At the line: "`File.Encrypt("Text.pvf");`", I get an IOException that says: 'The request is not supported.'. Now the `button1` method is called first. I do not know why this error comes up.

My pc: Windows7 64bit, .net 4.0, file system is NTFS as needed for `File.Encryption` method.

Please copy and paste my code to see if you can maybe spot the error. Perhaps I am missing something. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the drive is formatted as NTFS? The encryption bit isn't supported on FAT-formatted drives.

Comment: Dead certain. I did check that it is NTFS and it is

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows 7 Home Edition?

In Windows 7 Home Edition, it is not supported.
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/encrypt-contents-secure-data-greyed-out-t171160.html

Comment: That sucks. I am running Win7 Home Premium 64bit. Do you have any other encrypt/decrypt suggestions maybe? excluding serialization

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. U might search google for 3rd party encryption services. Can u please mark this as answer since it was 'Home Edition'?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my computer running Visual Studio 2010 in a WPF App 4.0 client profile. So it must be something with your user account and permissions. Try to save the file in another directory like the IsolatedStorage

Comment: U could slash away the File.Encrypt and explore to the file afterwards. Right click it for properties and go to Advanced. Is the checkbox "Encrypt contents to secure Data" available?

Comment: No, that is not avaliable. Any help?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your regional settings, see for example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821860